# Declaring String inside Public Method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to declare variables inside of a method. Unfourantly, i am getting the error "invalid expression term public" no matter what type of variable i am trying to declare

```
public void SerializeToXML(List<amzReport> amzReport)
{
     private String 4t4t;

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<amzReport>));
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\movie.xml");
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, amzReport);
    textWriter.Close();

}
```

UPDATED CODE(ERROR: "; Expected"):

```
/********************************************************************************/
   public void SerializeToXML(List<amzReport> amzReport)
        {
            String 4t4t;
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<amzReport>));
            TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\movie.xml");
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, amzReport);
            textWriter.Close();

    }
/********************************************************************************/
```

Comment: Inside a method you cannot use the `private` keyword, simple use `string _4t4t;`, i put underscore because variable names cannot begin with a number.

Comment: Addition to @AlessandroD'Andria point why do you declare a variable which you don't use?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use access modifier in a `method scope`, it should be like this:

```
String t4t = "";//must assign a value if you want to assign it to another var, pass it into a method (commonly saying: use it)
//otherwise no need to assign.
```

Comment: Oh come on. That won't compile.

Comment: Note that variable names can't start with a digit.

Comment: Fixed.. Sorry. I just randomly typed something to test out the variables.

Comment: @user1698144: It's always worth making test code realistic in terms of syntax. It doesn't need to do anything useful, but it helps if you don't have problems *except* the one you're trying to tackle.